# SQL: selecting the set of A not B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Two tables: left one is users_projects, right one is projects:
[image]

I want to select the projects that user 3 is not participating in (only p_ID 5 and 7).

I've tried `SELECT * FROM users_projects up INNER JOIN projects p ON p.p_ID=up.p_ID WHERE up.u_ID!=3`

but that also returns me p_ID 1 which both user 2 and 3 are a part of.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `select projectName from user_projects where p_ID not in (select p-id from users where u_id = 3);`

Comment: NOT IN is a bit dangerous... I recommend the null-safe NOT EXISTS instead.

Comment: @jarlh Can you add the NOT EXISTS query?

Comment: `select projectName from user_projects where p_ID NOT EXIST (select * from users where u_id = 3);` is better when it comes to NULL values because not in will always return nothing if there is null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  projects p LEFT JOIN users_projects up ON (p.p_ID = up.p_ID AND up.u_ID = 3)
WHERE 
  up.u_ID IS NULL
```

Basically select all Projects and join them with the `user_projects` of the desired user. Left join makes all rows from the `project` table appear even if the is no corresponding row in the `users_projects` table. These rows have all fields from the `users_projects` set to `NULL`, so we can just select those.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `JOIN` query, but a query with a non-correlated sub-select with a  `NOT IN()` predicate.

I hope the columns of the `projects` table are enough ...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  (         SELECT 1,'Apple'   -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
  UNION ALL SELECT 5,'Banna'   -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
  UNION ALL SELECT 7,'Carrot'  -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
  UNION ALL SELECT 8,'Durian') -- input data, don't use in 'real' query 
projects(p_id,p_name)
WHERE p_id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    p_id
  FROM 
    (         SELECT 2,1  -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
    UNION ALL SELECT 2,5  -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
    UNION ALL SELECT 2,7  -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
    UNION ALL SELECT 3,1  -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
    UNION ALL SELECT 3,8) -- input data, don't use in 'real' query
  users_projects(u_id,p_id)
  WHERE u_id=3
)
;

p_id|p_name
   7|Carrot
   5|Banna
```